# Can I change sdk installed in project based on scheme?

Tags: ios, swift, zoom-sdk

I need to use zoom sdk, and it turns out there are 2 versions, for device only and device+simulator, wheres device+simulator can't included in the app when you ship it for review on Apple.

Is there a way to change the sdk installed based on scheme (or some other solution)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1

1. Click the relevant framework from the Project Navigator
2. On the left bar navigate to the File Inspector
3. Under "Target Membership" make sure only the Production target is checked for
   the "DeviceOnly" framework and only the Development target is checked for the "All" framework

The above solution is only applicable if you already have a separate target for release and a separate one for development. If you don't want to keep separate targets, there is another (more complex) solution that involves creating a run script phase and writing a script that replaces the relevant framework files in the code base before compilation.